# OCAML module type and module compilation

Tags: module, compilation, ocaml

1) i have a signature

```
module type UINTSIG=
sig
type t
val create: t->t
end
```

2) I want to create two modules that use the above signature

so ideally i would like to keep the signature in 1, in a separate file from the implementation and signature files of the modules that use the the signature in 1.
My questions are

A) where should i put the signature in 1 above. Should i put it in uintsig.mli file ?
B) how do i express in the .mli/ml files of the modules that they use signature in 1 ?

Answer (score 3):

It's reasonable to put your module type definition into a file named uintsig.mli.

You can then refer to the module type from other files by the name `Uintsig.UINTSIG`.

(As a side comment, the module type doesn't seem to me to be well founded. There's no way to create a value of type `t` without already having a value of type `t`. But it's just an example, obviously.)